# Java and Web development: good practices to store custom sensitive data such as private keys, API keys, etc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, coding-style, sensitive-data

What do you advise to store custom sensitive data within a Spring MVC application (or within any other JAVA Web MVC application actually)? Let's say I've an API key and I need it to be available for my controllers. Several solutions I could think about:

**1-** Using a static class:

```
public final static String API_KEY = "my-api-key";
```

**2-** Using a context parameter (`web.xml`):

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>apiKey</param-name>
    <param-value>my-api-key</param-value>
</context-param>
```

**3-** Using a custom `.properties` file:

```
apiKey=my-api-key
```

**4-** Using a custom `.xml` file:

```
<entry key="apiKey">my-api-key</entry>
```

**5-** Any other idea/solution you could have :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how secure you need that information to be.

In options listed by you, I believe option (1)

```
public final static String API_KEY = "my-api-key";
```

is relatively safe as it the java file is compiled to class file and quick inspection of your distribution will not allow anyone to see the api-key, but downside is that it gets hard-coded and you cannot change it without a recompile.

I would suggest having a hard-coded password in code and then encrypt the key using something like DES. The encrypted key then can be stored as a properties file or whatever.

Comment: That's finally the solution I chose :)

Answer (score 2):

Any of the above seems fine, if you are happy that any developer/admin can see the key. You could also store it in a database, directory, etc.

This wouldn't be acceptable for user passwords as no-one should be able to see those. Passwords would be better stored as a one-way hash - I'm not a security expert, but I believe md5 is considered weak, others recommend something like SHA-256.

Other things you should probably consider are:

- file/directory permissions (which users/groups can read/write the file)
- whether it needs to be encrypted over the wire (in which case you'll need a public/private key)

Comment: Concerning the user passwords (for example), I already store their SHA hash in my database. But thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the spring-framework I would suggest using the [jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/) library.  I allows you to encrypt certain properties and externalize the master password to the registry or another location.

When going this route it is also advised to have a property file external of your application where the client can put their encrypted properties that override the default that is deliverd with your application.

Comment: Yeah, seems interesting! I'm not sure it's a good solution to store only API keys (for example), but I'll have a look. Thanks!